# Правильное использование тега main

Tags: html, css, html5, dom

Можно ли использовать тег main в качестве родительского для всей html-страницы после body? Чем его можно заменить, если не использовать div, а header и footer не подходят по смысловой нагрузке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли использовать тег main в качестве родительского для всей
>   html-страницы после body

Элемент  должен содержать главный контент вашей вебстраницы. Причем, все содержимое должно быть уникально на странице и не должно отображаться где-либо еще на сайте.

Повторяющийся на нескольких страницах контент (логотип, окно поиска, ссылки в футере и т.д.) не следует помещать внутри элемента.

Спецификация W3C описывает  следующим образом:

> Основное содержание документа или приложения. Область, содержащая
>   основные данные, которые непосредственно связаны или расширяют
>   основную тему документа или основной функционал приложения.

И `<main>` не предназначен для разбиения наполнения на части, он не влияет на структуру документа так, как это делают элементы `<article>`, `<nav>` или `<section>`

> Чем его можно заменить

Если по-правильному - то ничем.

Полезная ссылка https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main